# How to prevent html game pause when switch tab

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a HTML game with 'Egret', but when ever I switch to other tab, my game just pause automatically.

Is there any solution to prevent game pause?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Some more information would help.  Is Egret a game engine?  Google did not reveal much.  Also, some code that you think is causing this might help us help you.

Comment: If you are using js animation [This SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome) can help you out.

Comment: Yes, Egret is a game engine, using typescript. I think Google didn't reveal much is because Egret is made by Chinese.

Comment: I have done some research about this issue.
Some game engine had provide this function, like Phaser engine.
(http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/10847-gamestagedisablevisibilitychange-not-working/)

Comment: try to add some code

Comment: I just wondering, why Facebook game can keep running, even in other tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the game's tick is based on the [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). And this function is based on the browser's repaint. If you switch to another tab, the repaint is stop, so the `requestAnimationFrame` stop.

If you really need your game run after switch to another tab, use the `setInterval` as your game's tick with time `1000/60`.

But this is not so performance as the requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need.